# ORA-00936: expression absente + ORA-02063: précédant line de LIENBD_S1 Oracle

Tags: oracle, dblink

Can you help me find the error here? I do not understand why it is not working..

`CREATE TABLE Commande2 AS (SELECT * FROM Commande@lienBD_S1 WHERE numF NOT IN (SELECT numF FROM Fournisseur1@lienBD_S1));`

When I execute the query without the CREATE TABLE like this

```
SELECT * FROM Commande@lienBD_S1 WHERE numF NOT IN (SELECT numF FROM Fournisseur1@lienBD_S1);
```

it works.

Comment: What happens if you remove the brackets enclosing the SELECT?

Comment: I still have the same error :/

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74631/ora-02049-and-ora-02063-errors) or [this](https://www.tekstream.com/oracle-error-messages/ora-02063-preceding-string-error/) helps

Comment: this query works for me without causing any problem.  what is the error?

Comment: When you run the standalone query are you retrieving all rows (as the `create` has to), or just the first page/chunk? My only immediate thought is that one of the remote tables is actually a view that is calling a function, and it is that function which is throwing the error - from a row you haven't manually fetched - but that seems a bit convoluted and unlikely...

Comment: no i didn't create views yet. _Fournisseur1_ is a fragment of the main table _Fournisseur_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an other way to make it work !
I created a table `Fournisseur2` That contain the the lines that are NOT IN `Fournisseur1` and used it to create my table `Commande2` like this :

```
CREATE TABLE Fournisseur2 AS (SELECT * FROM Fournisseur@lienBD_S1 WHERE ville <> 'Paris');
CREATE TABLE Commande2 AS (SELECT * FROM Commande@lienBD_S1 WHERE numF IN (SELECT numF FROM Fournisseur2));
```